# Extjs: Nested Apps

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to move a rather complex app to Extjs. In our current application we used a very modular approach where we structured the app into multiple sub-apps, which were loaded by a main app. I'd like to reuse this approach with Extjs using a fresh "MVC base" per sub-app.

At the moment I've got a simple main app and simple customer-sub-app. Both work nicely independently. But once I try to add the customer to main app, I just see a blank area.

Is there maybe a more recommended way of doing this?

My main app:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'ISA',
    appFolder: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout:'border',
            defaults: {
                collapsible: true,
                split: false,
                bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
            },
            items: [{
                title: 'ProcessBar',
                region: 'north',
                height: 150,
                cmargins: '5 0 0 0'
            },{
                title: 'Main Area',
                id:'desktop',
                xtype:"panel",
                collapsible:false,
                region:'center',
                margins: '5 0 0 0',
                cmargins: '0 0 0 0',
                height:300,
                items:[{
                    type:"ISA.extensions.customer",
                    height:300
                }]

            }]
        });
    }
});
```

My Customer App:

```
Ext.define('ISA.extensions.customer',{
    extend:'Ext.app.Application',
    alias:'customer',
    name: 'ISA.extensions.customer',
    appFolder: 'app',    
    controllers: [
        'Users'
    ],
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            layout:'border',
            height: 400,
            renderTo:  "desktop",
            defaults: {
                collapsible: false,
                split: false,
                bodyStyle: 'padding:0px'

            },
            items: [{
                title: 'Customer App',
                region:'center',
                margins: '0 0 0 0',
                cmargins: '0 0 0 0',
                width: 175,
                minSize: 100,
                maxSize: 250,
                items: {
                    xtype: 'userlist'
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});


Ext.define('ISA.extensions.customer.view.user.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.userlist',

    title : 'All Users',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = {
            fields: ['name', 'email'],
            data  : [
                {name: 'Ed',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                {name: 'Tommy', email: 'tommy@sencha.com'}
            ]
        };

        this.columns = [
            {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name',  flex: 1},
            {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1}
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.define('ISA.extensions.customer.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: [
        'user.List'
    ],
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'viewport > panel': {
                render: this.onPanelRendered
            }
        });
    },

    onPanelRendered: function() {
        console.log('The customer list was rendered');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current ExtJs MVC approach assume you have all your code inside one app. You can divide different functionality using different views, controller and stores but the app should be single.

Comment: You can have a set of common shared components though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185027

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/SubAppDemo;

If this is of no help I can tell you quite a lot about dynamic loading of views/controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution ist using dependency injection: http://deftjs.org/