# Under ExtJS 4 is there a way to load external components?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, components, code-reuse

I am trying to set up my ExtJS 4 project so I have three top level applications, for example,

> /foo/app.js 
>    /bar/app.js 
>    /baz/app.js

Each 'top level' application is a separate ExtJS application, each with their own loaders. There are some cases were I will have general components that I want to share between all three applications, so I have `/components` top level directory.

If I have a component name say ComponentA,

> /components/componenta.js

How would I go about getting ComponentA into all three applications, so it could referenced or extended by the individual application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add this same loader into each of the applications `app.js` file.

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Common', '../components/');
```

Then give your common components the same namespace when you define them and place them in the components top level folder.

**`componenta.js`**

```
Ext.define('Common.componenta', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    title: 'Component A'
});
```

Then the Common namespace will be available for you to extend in each application

```
Ext.define('Foo.panel', {
    extend: 'Common.componenta',
    title: 'Foo Panel'
});
```

Comment: Upvoted.Here is a recent discussion on the Sencha forums that describe exactly this pattern in greater detail. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238496-How-to-extend-a-Ext.app.Application&p=875700

Comment: Thanks, that was a lot more straight forward then I thought it would be.